# Generate binary image using coordinate vectors

Tags: c++, c++14, iterator

I have a matrix `M` of size `[n_rows, n_cols]` and a list of `x` and `y` pixel coordinates. I use these coordinates to draw a binary image. Here is my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> y;

// fill x and y

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> M(n_rows, std::vector<unsigned int>(n_cols));

std::vector<std::vector<double>>::const_iterator iter_row_x = x.begin();
std::vector<std::vector<double>>::const_iterator iter_row_y = y.begin();

for (; iter_row_x != x.end(); ++iter_row_x, ++iter_row_y) {
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter_col_x = iter_row_x[0].begin();
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter_col_y = iter_row_y[0].begin();
    for (; iter_col_x != iter_row_x[0].end(); ++iter_col_x, ++iter_col_y) {
        unsigned int i = unsigned int(*iter_col_x);
        unsigned int j = unsigned int(*iter_col_y);
        M[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to achieve this? My code above looks a bit bulky and error-prone for such a simple task.

Comment: Do you need 2D-matrices for x and y? Would something like `std::vector<Point> xy` suffice? (where `Point` is a `struct` with members `double x` and `double y`.)

Comment: @MikaelH I need 2D-matrices since I have several objects.

Comment: Okay, but I assume `std::vector<std::vector<Point>> xy` would be fine?

Comment: @MikaelH For only one object, yes. But I have many objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**auto**

Automatic type deduction is especially welcoming for iterators, as their types are bulky. We can rewrite to

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> y;

// fill x and y

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> M(n_rows, std::vector<unsigned int>(n_cols));

auto iter_row_x = x.cbegin(); //note cbegin to get const_iterator
auto iter_row_y = y.cbegin();

for (; iter_row_x != x.end(); ++iter_row_x, ++iter_row_y) {
    auto iter_col_x = iter_row_x->cbegin(); // iter_row_x[0].cbegin() = iter_row_x->cbegin()
    auto iter_col_y = iter_row_y->cbegin();
    for (; iter_col_x != iter_row_x[0].end(); ++iter_col_x, ++iter_col_y) {
        auto i = static_cast<unsigned int>(*iter_col_x); // be explicit about which cast you are using. Now you do not need to specify the type twice.
        auto j = static_cast<unsigned int>(*iter_col_y);
        M[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

But it's still wordy. Having separate vectors for x and y seems unnecessary, since it is expected that they should be of same length. Better create a structure for xy and create only one vector.

```
struct Point 
{
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

Then we have

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> xy;

// fill xy

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> M(n_rows, std::vector<unsigned int>(n_cols));

for (auto iter_row_xy = xy.cbegin() ; iter_row_xy != xy.end(); ++iter_row_xy) {
    for (auto iter_col_xy = iter_row_xy->cbegin(); iter_col_x != iter_row_x[0].end(); ++iter_col_x, ++iter_col_y) {
        auto i = static_cast<unsigned int>(*iter_col_xy.x);
        auto j = static_cast<unsigned int>(*iter_col_xy.y);
        M[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

But we can do even better by using for range:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> xy;

// fill xy

std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> M(n_rows, std::vector<unsigned int>(n_cols));

for (const auto& elements : xy){
    for (const auto& point : elements){
        auto i = static_cast<unsigned int>(point.x);
        auto j = static_cast<unsigned int>(point.y);
        M[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: And with C++17 you can use structured bindings to simplify the inner for-loop: `for (auto [x, y]: elements) {unsigned int i = x, j = y; M[i][j] = 1;}`